# Pokemon Go: Gym Badge Over-completed?

Tags: pokemon-go

[image: Gym badges status bars]

Despite having already filled the status bar under Sugar Creek Country Club, it's back at zero. It seemed to have lapped or "overcompleted" itself and started again. Is this possible?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

When you upgrade your gym badge, the status bar restarts. You can upgrade your badge from no colour to bronze, bronze to silver, and silver to gold. Once it's gold, the status bar disappears. Upgrading your badge is a good thing, as it increases the number of items you get from the PokeSpot (1 from bronze, 2 from silver, 3 from gold), and if the gym is an ex-raid gym it reportedly increases your change of obtaining an ex-raid pass.

In your case, you appear to have upgraded your Sugar Creek Country Club badge from bronze to silver. The status bar has restarted as it is now recording the status towards obtaining the gold badge.